# Remain pod directory files while mounting a "hostpath PV " to pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, volume, mount, kubernetes-pvc

What I want is that mount a `hostpath` `pv` to my `pod` directory for example `/usr/share/nginx/html/` and my files at this directory be remain.

I have a `nginx` image that i have `index.html` file in it's `/usr/share/nginx/html/` directory. 
And when i want to orchestrate it with `Kubernetes` and make a pod and use a `PV` for make it persistent, it mount the `hostpath` to container `/usr/share/nginx/html/` directory and after that my index.html will be gone .
these are my manifests

`Dockerfile` :

```
FROM nginx
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
VOLUME /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And in my `.` directory I have `index.html`

`pod.yaml` :

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: task-pv-pod23
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage2
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: task-pv-claim2
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: meysambbb/nginx:2
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - name: task-pv-storage2
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

`pv.yaml`:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume2
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/2/data/"
```

`pvc.yaml` :

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

When I run my pod without `VolumeMount` and when i run `curl <POD_IP>` it show my index.html contents but when I use `pv` and `VolumeMount` it show 403 error 
Is it possible to mount `hostpath` and have container files in same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Is this data static (you build it into the image), or does it change (you want a volume to persist it)?  What behavior do you want when this content changes?

The combination of options you're trying to specify here doesn't really make sense.  Kubernetes doesn't do the thing Docker does where if you mount an empty volume into a container it's filled with matching content from the image.  Even so, if you make a change and rebuild the image, neither plain Docker nor Kubernetes will modify the volume; it will still have the old content.

My intuition for a tree of HTML files and related assets is that it's probably more "like data" than "like code", and so I would use a plain nginx image, copy the tree into the directory you're mounting as a hostpath, and proceed that way.  When this tree changes, you'd make the changes in the hostpath directory.

Comment: Yes I have this files in image and also i want a volume to persist it but i want my container files be remain in that directory i mount my pv hostpath to it. i want my files in /usr/share/nginx/html be remain while i mount my hostpath into it

Comment: Neither Kubernetes nor plain Docker has that option.